# How would you obtain the first and last items in a Queue?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections, queue

Say I have a rolling collection of values where I specify the size of the collection and any time a new value is added, any old values beyond this specified size are dropped off. Obviously (and I've tested this) the best type of collection to use for this behavior is a Queue:

```
myQueue.Enqueue(newValue)
If myQueue.Count > specifiedSize Then myQueue.Dequeue()
```

However, what if I want to calculate the difference between the first and last items in the Queue? Obviously I can't access the items by index. But to switch from a Queue to something implementing IList seems like overkill, as does writing a new Queue-like class. Right now I've got:

```
Dim firstValue As Integer = myQueue.Peek()
Dim lastValue As Integer = myQueue.ToArray()(myQueue.Count - 1)
Dim diff As Integer = lastValue - firstValue
```

That call to `ToArray()` bothers me, but a superior alternative isn't coming to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't C# have a Dequeue type?

Comment: No, C# hasn't any type, .Net is what has types; and .Net hasn't a Dequeue type, it has a Queue/Queue<T> type which has a Dequeue method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One thing you could do is have a temporary variable that stores the value that was just enqueued because that will be the last value and so the variable can be accessed to get that value.

Comment: At about the same time you provided this answer I realized how straightforward the solution (what you've suggested, basically) would be. Good call!

Answer (score 18):

Seems to me if you need quick access to the first item in the list, then you're using the wrong data structure. Switch a LinkedList instead, which conveniently has First and Last properties.

Be sure you only add and remove items to the linked list using AddLast and RemoveFirst to maintain the Queue property. To prevent yourself from inadvertantly violating the Queue property, consider creating a wrapper class around the linked list and exposing only the properties you need from your queue.

Comment: Unfortunate but better than keeping track of the last added outside of the data structure itself.

Answer (score 10):

```
public class LastQ<T> : Queue<T>
{
    public T Last { get; private set; }

    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
         Last = item;
         base.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Obviously this basic class should be more robust to do things like protect the Last property on an empty queue.  But this should be enough for the basic idea.

Comment: Ha! This is almost VERBATIM the code I just wrote. (Only difference is the class name and I put Last = item after base.Enqueue(item)).

Comment: What happens when the last element is removed? How would you set `Last` to the second last element then?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to keep track of the last value added to the `Queue`, then use the `myQueue.Peek()` function to see the "first" (meaning next) item in the list without removing it.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use a deque (**d**ouble-**e**nded **queue**).

I don't think there is one built into System.Collections(.Generic) but here's some info on the data structure. If you implemented something like this you could just use PeekLeft() and PeekRight() to get the first and last values.

Of course, it will be up to you whether or not implementing your own deque is preferable to dealing with the unsexiness of ToArray(). :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/deque.aspx